# Characters are detached from skeleton when command line rendering in blender 3.0

Tags: rendering, command-line

I've just upgraded to 3.0 and am having issues with command line rendering. When I render using command line, my characters are no longer attached to their skeletons as you can see below. When I render within the blender gui everything is fine as in the second image.

[image]
[image]

I'm using a project that I created in 2.92 so maybe this is an issue. Any ideas why this is happening? Is this a bug that others have seen?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a project I made in 3.0. I was able to fix it by checking if the command line version of Blender matches the one you made your project in. In my case the command line triggered Blender 2.8 instead of 3.0 causing this issue. If you're on Windows you can change the PATH variable to choose which version of Blender CMD will prefer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, I hadn't thought of that